# How can I get my swagger specification (file json) from my bean with annotations swagger

Tags: swagger

I developed a service REST with annotations swagger, Is there any way to obtain the specification file from this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Which framework/tool are you using? I believe the spec file is generated during the buid.

Comment: Yes it's true. I'm using swagger-ui and it's generated with the build. Thanks